# How to use the mirror option of apt-cacher-ng for debootstrap?

Tags: scripts, debootstrap

I run `debootstrap` like this:

```
sudo debootstrap --verbose --arch=amd64 zesty chroot
```

I have already installed `apt-cacher-ng`.

How do I make them work together so that when I run debootstrap multiple times I use the cache instead of repeatedly downloading the same packages?

I have tried using the MIRROR option and setting the http_proxy variable but it errors when I run offline:

```
$ sudo http_proxy="http://localhost:3142" debootstrap --verbose --arch=amd64 zesty chroot http://localhost:3142/uburep
I: Retrieving InRelease 
I: Failed to retrieve InRelease
I: Retrieving Release 
E: Failed getting release file http://localhost:3142/uburep/dists/zesty/Release
```

I used `http://localhost:3142/uburep` because that is what I found in the cache:

```
$ find /var/cache/apt-cacher-ng -name Release
/var/cache/apt-cacher-ng/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-security/Release
/var/cache/apt-cacher-ng/uburep/dists/zesty-updates/Release
/var/cache/apt-cacher-ng/uburep/dists/zesty-backports/Release
/var/cache/apt-cacher-ng/uburep/dists/zesty/Release
```

[I tried adding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334303/failed-getting-release-file-while-running-debootstrap-with-sudo) `Defaults        env_keep += "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"` to /etc/sudoers (via sudo visudo) but it didn't help either.

If I remove the MIRROR option and run debootstrap offline it then doesn't seem to use apt-cacher-ng at all (note how it is not looking for localhost any more).

```
E: Failed getting release file http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty/Release
```

Comment: What Ubuntu version is this?

Comment: zesty. I am creating a zesty iso distribution from within zesty.

Comment: You shouldn't use the apt-cacher-ng URL as a mirror. It should be used a proxy only.

Comment: I updated the question to demonstrate that removing the MIRROR option doesn't help.

Comment: Does apt-cacher's logs indicate any attempt to access it when used only as a proxy?

Answer (score 6):

There is a trick to get this to work without explicit proxy settings. You *can* in fact use your configured `apt-cacher-ng` as a mirror URL like so:

```
http://localhost:3142/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

So as you can see after specifying the base URL to your `apt-cacher-ng` instance you can then give a server and a path as per [this Wiki article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors). I've used this method in my own bootstrap scripts and it works like a charm.

Note: you may want to verify that your `apt-cacher-ng` instance is running by checking with `lsof -i :3142` (requires the `lsof` package).

Comment: I mention in the question that I am using the mirror option and it doesn't work when I am offline. What are you doing differently here?

Comment: 0xC… is using the same option as you.